# How to conditionally define a new style in tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, xstring

I define a new tcolorbox option(key) named `background color`. If the valve given to it is a decimal, the backgound of the tcolorbox will have an effect of transparent --  eg. `background color=0`, else the box will have a back color -- eg. `background=red`.

It works all right(in `Test 1` and `Test 2`) except when it is used in a customized tcolorbox `\mybox`(`Test 3`).

I suspect that the problem comes from the defination of `bacground color`. So, what is the correct way in tcolorbox to define a style whose value is on depends?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tcbset{%
  background color/.code={%
    \IfDecimal{#1}
    {\tcbset{standard jigsaw,opacityback=#1}}
    {\tcbset{standard jigsaw,opacityback=1,colback=#1}}
  }
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NewDocumentCommand{\mybox}{sO{}}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        breakable,
    before skip=1ex,after skip=1em,
    colback=black!5,colframe=black!50,
    boxrule=0.2mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    boxed title style={%
            frame code={%
            \path[fill=tcbcolback!30!black]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
            arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
            \path[left color=tcbcolback!60!black,right color=tcbcolback!60!black,
            middle color=tcbcolback!80!black]
            ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
            [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
            -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            [sharp corners]-- cycle;
            },
            interior engine=empty,
    },
        drop fuzzy shadow southwest,
        colbacktitle=green,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\normalsize}{\Large},
    title=\IfBooleanTF{#1}{Abstract}{Contents},
        #2
    ]
  \tableofcontents%
\end{tcolorbox}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
%Test 1:
\begin{tcolorbox}[background color=0]
  Here the new option ``background color'' works fine
\end{tcolorbox}

%Test 2:
\mybox% This also does work

%Test 3:
\mybox[background color=0]% Introducing the new option "background color" causes error.

\section{first section}
\section{second section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use the skin `standard jigsaw` if you want to use tikz code on the frame, you need an `enhanced` skin for this.

Comment: Thank you @Ulrike Fischer You mean `\tcbset{enhanced,opacityback=#1}` instead of `\tcbset{standard jigsaw,opacityback=#1}` ? This seems causing lost of  control of the opacity.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer I try with `enhanced jigsaw`, and then the content of TOC which should have been shipout in an tcolorbox by `\mybox` disappears(in Test 3), why and how to deal with this?

Comment: @lyl with the Ulrike Fisher comment and  comment test2 in your code